# I'm seeing an out of network provider for physical therapy

Tags: united-states, health-insurance

I'm seeing an out of network provider for physical therapy. They told me I pay nothing and once I get checks from my insurance company, I sign them over to them.

I received some checks and on the EOB it states The amount billed, the amount paid (by insurance), and then the amount that I owe the provider.

The amount it states that I owe provider is less then the amount paid (by insurance).

Why is that?

Comment: But you said that you didn't pay anything.

Comment: I didn't - when I say "amount paid" I meant the amount the ins paid on the check.

Comment: I edited the question.  If you don't like the changes, you can revert them.

Answer (score 1):

This sounds like [balance billing](https://www.healthcare.gov/glossary/balance-billing/) (see also: [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Balance_billing)). For an in-network provider, your insurance will have agreed upon rates with the provider. For an out-of-network provider, they'll pay only what they think is fair. You're responsible for the rest.

(In some states, there are protections against balance billing. I presume your insurer is already aware of these, but check anyways.)

> The amount it states that I owe provider is less then the amount paid (by insurance). Why is that?

The two amounts are sort of unrelated. If your provider bills $1,000, and insurance deems $100 fair, you'll owe $900. If your insurer deems $900 fair, you'd only owe $100. A *small* balance bill is better than a *big* one, but it sucks in either case.